# setting/changing environment variables in firebase project using cloud functions in node

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to set or change the **firebase environment variables** using cloud functions.In my case,I like to change the environment variable each and every 1 hour

Comment: What "firebase environment variables" are you referring to?

Comment: I gave the most likely answer below. But this very much sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you describe what you're trying to accomplish with this approach, it's more likely that someone can help you accomplish **that**.

Answer (score 0):

The [environment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) for a Cloud Functions image is determine when you deploy your code. You cannot change this environment from inside the environment, including from within your Cloud Function code.